# Installing Ubuntu on 3TB Hard Drive

Tags: software-installation

Recently, I bought a desktop PC (ASUS Z87-PRO V) with 3TB hard disk. I have been trying to install Linux on it. It has been installed well but it drops on BIOS after installation. I have tried different versions of Linux but the same thing happened, it just went to BIOS after installation. Would some one please help me with that? please, give me simple answers with details since I am a beginner.

Comment: Are you installing in UEFI boot mode or BIOS boot mode? With a 3TB drive you do have to have gpt partitioning. So with UEFI, you have to have an efi partition preferably at start of drive, or with BIOS boot you have to have a 1 or 2MB unformatted partition with the bios_grub flag. I often suggest both and then you can just reinstall grub to boot in either mode. Shows boot screens from installer for both BIOS & UEFI. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Thanks a lot for your good answer. I did it and it worked. Thanks again :)